# html has no effect by css

Tags: python, html, css, sockets, networking

I have a simple Web Server made using Python Socket. This server has only two file, 'home.html' and 'home.css' in a templates folder. But when I visit home.html I see no effect by my home.css file. I checked Microsoft Edge's DevTools and It showed a black home.css file.

My Folders:

```
Website
   - server.py
   - templates
       - home.html
       - home.css
```

**home.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>title name</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="body_container">
        <p>This is body..</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

**home.css code:**

```
body{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**server.py:**

```
import time
import socket
import threading

class WebServer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "192.168.0.101"
        self.port = 80
        self.content_dir = 'templates'

    def _generate_headers(self, response_code):
        header = ''
        if response_code == 200:
            header += 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'
        elif response_code == 404:
            header += 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n'

        time_now = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        header += 'Date: {now}\n'.format(now=time_now)
        header += 'Server: Orasae\n'
        header += 'Connection: close\n\n' # Signal that connection will be closed after completing the request
        return header

    def handle_client(self, conn, addr):
        """
        Handles Client Connection and Serves Files From self.content_dir.

        parameters:
            - conn: Client Socket Object from self.server.accept();
            - addr: Client Address from self.server.accept();
        """
        PACKET_SIZE = 1024
        CONNECTION = True

        while CONNECTION:
            data = conn.recv(PACKET_SIZE).decode() # Receive Data From Client and Decode it.
            if not data:
                CONNECTION = False

            response = self._generate_headers(200).encode()
            
            directory = data.split(" ")[1] # gets directory for requested file
            
            if directory == '/' or directory == '/home':
                f = open(f"{self.content_dir}/home.html", 'rb')
                htmlCode = f.read()
                f.close()

                response += htmlCode

            conn.send(response)
            conn.close()
            CONNECTION = False


    def _listen(self):
        """
        Listens For Any Connection on self.port and Calls self.handle_client For
        Handling Client Request/Respond. 
        """
        self.server.listen(1)
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.server.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(conn, addr)).start()

    def start(self):
        """
        Attempts to create and bind to a socket to launch it.
        """
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            print(f"Starting Server on {self.host}:{self.port}")
            self.server.bind((self.host, self.port))
            print(f"Started Server on {self.host}:{self.port}")
        except:
            print(f"[ERROR] Couldn't Start Server on port {self.port}")

        self._listen()
```

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: @MohithReddy you are right. I never told my server How to act on that Request. Thanks  for your Help!

Comment: I hope you can be thankful by accepting my answer :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is never reading `home.css` file. When client requests you need to parse the request and find the file client is requesting for, and deliver it accordingly. By the way, HTTP line delimiters are `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
html,body{background-color:#ccc}
```

OR just testing purpose try

```
<body bgcolor="black">
```

Comment: That should work. But in case of making a real website, I need a separate css file. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Sadman Hasin I Know and I just Tell you testing Purpose what is going on if that worked that means you have another problem.. May be you understand what I mean

Comment: I have solved my problem. It is because when I put link .css file in .html, the browser again sends a request to my server for .css file but I haven't told my server how to response on that request, now that I have, It works fine! Thanks for trying helping me.